# Absolutely Positioned elements Affecting Another elements on delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have more than one div that is positioned absolute and dynamically created by clicking on a button. Once clicked, they are placed in a container that is positioned relative, and I have a button on each div that when clicking on it, will delete the div, the problem is when deleting the div, it will affect the others positions.

```js
function create() {
  var $home = $('<div class="cabine"></div>');
  $("#container").append($home); 
}
```

```css
.cabine {                   /*class that all div's share*/
  position: absolute;
  top:5%;
  left:10%;
  width:135px;
  height:135px;
  float:left;
  background: red;
}

#container {            /* Where the div's are placed*/
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(wall.jpg);
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="create()">Create Cabine</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Please provide a runnable code or fiddle..so that i can fix the issue

Comment: @RitwikaDas ok i'll add one just give me a minute , 
thank you

Comment: .container should be #container in the CSS

Answer (score 0):

In html you have `#container` instead of `.container`.